# What is Proj $\mathbb{C}[x,y][z]/\langle xz-yz\rangle$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

Assuming that $x,y$ have weight $0$ and $z$ has weight $1$,
$$
R= \mathbb{C}[x,y][z]/\langle xz-yz\rangle = \mathbb{C}[x,y]\oplus 
( \oplus_{i\geq 1}\mathbb{C}[x]z^i), 
$$ 
what closed subvariety is $\text{Proj } R$? How do you see that?  Could this be the empty set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non, it is not empty. Denote by $A=\mathbb C[x,y]$, $f=x-y\in A$. Then
$R=A[z]/fz$. So 
$$\mathrm{Proj}(R)=V_+(f)\cup V_+(z)=V_+(f)=\mathrm{Proj}((A/fA)[z])=\mathrm{Spec}(A/fA)\simeq \mathbb A^1_{\mathbb C}.$$ 
The middle equality is because $V_+(z)=\emptyset$ ($z$ generates the irrelevant ideal).

Comment: Why is the Proj(  ) = Spec(  ) equality true?